# Does the sd-ext partition get wiped out after flashing a different ROM?

Tags: cyanogenmod, partitions, miui

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace using its official CyanogenMod build. I wanted to try this MIUI ROM for a change:

http://forums.miui.us/showthread.php?22816-ROM-MIUI-us-2-8-3-for-galaxy-ace

Everything went fine, except that it doesn't see the 1GB sd-ext partition now. I don't know if it's just unmounted because my sdcard partition size stayed the same. Does the process really do that?

I'll check the recovery menu once I'm done backing up my sd card. But if you have any ideas, please do share them. Thank you.

Edit: Nothing in the recovery menu helped. I'm now about to re-create the sd-ext partition.

Comment: The partition should not have been touched, AFAIK (it is the one on SD for App2SD+, correct?). Maybe your new ROM doesn't recognize/support its file system? On my good-old HTC Buzz, CM7 also did not recognize it, though it's still there...

Answer (score 1):

I think your build f MIUI doesnt have the code for mounting the SD-ext partition on boot.
To check this, open the init.d folder in your new ROM and see if it has any file relating to Sd-ext.

This link has a init.d script for mounting the SD-ext partition [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1971689)

Answer (score 0):

Get [MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) which once installed in your computer, will be show all partitions on your SD card and maybe able to to restore old partitions, if you haven't wiped your SD card yet.

Mini wizard is for your computer and get a external card reader and insert the SD card or connect your phone in USB mass storage mode to see the partitions.

Comment: A link would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Check the storage capacity of your mounted sdcard. If it is 1 Gb less than the capacity, it means the other partition is still present but not mounted as Izzy commented.

You can Mount the partition as Aftab Khan suggested.